# Redirect all Customer Portal traffic to Force website

Tags: force.com, customer-portal

I have recently made the transition from my Customer Portal for client access to a full fledged Force.com website.

Although I have updated all links to the force website, I believe there could be some users that have simply bookmarked the portal URL. How can I force users to be redirected to the new force site when they load the customer portal (including even the homepage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have placed this piece of javascript at the bottom of my header document used in the Customer Portal template.

```
<script type="text/javscript">    
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
</script>
```